# How to compress multiple files in a folder into the one compressed folder?

Tags: powershell, compression

I try to automate a repetitive scenario by Powershell script:

I have a compressed (*.zip) folder with multiple files (*.XML) in it.

My scenario is to:

- uncompressed this folder located in: `C:\Users\*\Downloads`
- changed value inside a specific  in each file
- compress all the file into a folder with a specific name (format: `AppName.Version.zip`) that will be located in the same path: `C:\Users\*\Downloads`.

Questions:

1. How do I compress the folder again so that by clicking on the compress folder I'll see immediately the files (zipped folder>files) and not a folder then the files (zipped folder>files)
2. Compress and Expand commands are yelling about the folder name format of and therefore those commands are failed to their job. How do I get over it?

```
     $languageString = Read-Host ...
     $replaceString = '<value>' + $languageString
     $file = Get-Childitem "c:\users\*\Downloads\app.version.zip" -Recurse
     $originalFileName = $file.Name
     $absoluteFilePath = $file.FullName
     $rename-item -path $absoluteFilePath -newname translate.zip
     $file = Get-Childitem "c:\users\*\Downloads\translate.zip" -Recurse
     $absoluteFilePath = $file.FullName
     $unzipFilePath = $absoluteFilePath.Substring(0, $absoluteFilePath.LastIndexOf('.'))
     expand-archive -path $absoluteFilePath -destinationpath $unzipFilePath
     $files = @(Get-Childitem "c:\users\*\Downloads\*.xml)
     foreach ($file in $files)
     {
        (Get-Content -path $file.FullName -Raw) -replace '<value>' , $replaceString | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName

    #this line makes problems...

     Compress-Archive -path $unzipFilePath -Destinationpath $unzipFilePath -Force
```

Comment: Please provide us the code you are using to compress the files and to uncompressed it. And please use fake names instead of special characters like `*` if you are worried about personal information leaking.

Comment: * char is for running the script in different machines / users.

Comment: It looks like the `{` after `Foreach` command doesn't have a matching `}`. Can you add the error message you're seeing to confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it in three steps:
1. unzip in a temporary clean location.
2. change your files there
3. zip that location back.

the code would have the functions:

```
function Unzip_archive ($ArchiveFullPath, $Temp_Work_Fld) {
    try {
        #unzip
        Add-Type -assembly 'system.io.compression.filesystem'
        [io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory($ArchiveFullPath, $Temp_Work_Fld)
    }
    catch {
        throw "Failed to unzip the artifact"
    }
    Remove-Item $ArchiveFullPath -Force #only if you want to delete the archive
}

function CreateZipArchive($FolderToArchive, $ZipArchiveFullName){ 
    $source = Get-ChildItem * -Directory | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "$FolderToArchive"}
    write-host "`nArchiving: $source ........."
    Add-Type -Assembly system.IO.compression.filesystem
    $compressionlevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $ZipArchiveFullName, $compressionlevel, $true)
    write-host "nDone !"
}
```

then just call the functions before and after doing your changes in the temporary folder